# CS:GO rippling lag

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I have recently been experiencing problems with the latest version of CS:GO. In-game, whenever I attempt to move, after a short time, the screen will freeze and appear to do something that I can only describe as a ripple. Soon after, I will teleport backwards to where I was a few seconds ago. Any ideas?

Comment: sounds like your internet.

Comment: Could you give us a screenshot? (Usually, this "rippling effect" can be achieved by somehow leaving the map bounds)

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by either your internet lag or the server lag. Most Valve servers have no lag so it must be your internet on Valve servers.

Comment: Valve CSGO servers are pretty terrible in my experience. So...